# How to restart the app with the button in a flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I restart the app in Flutter and call the main again?

I tried Phoenix.rebirth(context) but the main is not called again

Comment: Seems a bit like an XY Problem. Why would you like to restart your app? What happens that cannot be handled by your normal state management?

Answer (score 2):

Use [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) flutter package.

###### How to use it?

1. Add the package to pubspec.yaml dependency:

```
dependencies:
  restart_app: ^1.1.2
```

2. Import package:

```
import 'package:restart_app/restart_app.dart';
```

3. Call the restartApp method where ever you want:

```
onPressed: () {
  /// Fill webOrigin only when your new origin is different than the app's origin
  Restart.restartApp(webOrigin: '[your main route]');
}
```

Comment: Just as an update, the package is updated to v1.2.0 and now it supports iOS platform as well.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily there's a plugin called phoniex to do it https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix sadly it only works on iOS.

Try this [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) plugin
A simple package that helps you to restart the whole android app with a single function call. It supports android only

If you need to restart the app for both android and iOS. You can give it a try from the below-mentioned code

```
void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    Restart.restartApp();
  } else {
    Phoenix.rebirth(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two options:

**First Solution**
is to restart ALL APP (Native restart) using this packages
[phoenix_native](https://pub.dev/packages/phoenix_native) or [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app)

Note: you have to stop and run app again after adding the package

**Best Solution**
As per this article : [How can I refresh application current screen after changing language in flutter?](https://www.ifeps.net/2024/01/cleaneast-way-how-to-restart-app-after.html)

This code cleanest way to do it

```
//2. Go back till no route (Restart)
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => false);

// Navigate to first widget to the app **AppRoot()**  
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AppRoot()),
);
```